# Check the count of column value is equal to one based on condition in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have two tables

**Student**

```
StudentId    |  StudentName
----------   |  --------------
1            |  John
2            |  Susan
3            |  Andy
4            |  Joe
```

**Department**

```
StudentId    |    DepartmentId
----------   |    ------------
1            |    123
1            |    234
2            |    123
2            |    456
3            |    123
4            |    456
```

Each student can be in multiple departments but I have to find those students which are only in one department like student 3 and 4

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

Use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`

```
SELECT s.StudentId,s.StudentName
FROM Department d
JOIN Student s ON s.StudentId=d.StudentId
GROUP BY s.StudentId,s.StudentName
HAVING COUNT(d.DepartmentId)=1
```

And if you also want to show students which not in Department table

```
SELECT s.StudentId,s.StudentName
FROM Department d
RIGHT JOIN Student s ON s.StudentId=d.StudentId
GROUP BY s.StudentId,s.StudentName
HAVING COUNT(d.DepartmentId)<=1
```

Variant with `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT s.StudentId,s.StudentName
FROM Student s
LEFT JOIN Department d ON s.StudentId=d.StudentId
GROUP BY s.StudentId,s.StudentName
HAVING COUNT(d.DepartmentId)<=1
```

Comment: RIGHT JOIN... Most people have problem enough with LEFT JOIN. It's much easier to understand "main table left join optional data" instead of "optional data right join main table".

Comment: @jarlh - Yes, I agree with you. I supplemented my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Simply join them & aggregate them by `Group by` clause with `having`.. `count()` function

```
SELECT s.StudentId, s.StudentName
FROM student s
     JOIN Department d ON d.StudentId = s.StudentId
GROUP BY s.StudentId, s.StudentName
HAVING COUNT(d.DepartmentId) = 1;
```

Result :

```
studentid   studentname 
3           Andy        
4           Joe
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IN` with `department` table group by `StudentId` alongwith having `count(Student_Id) = 1` in sub-query  as below.

```
SELECT *
FROM student s
WHERE s.StudentId IN (
        SELECT d.StudentId
        FROM Department d
        GROUP BY d.StudentId
        HAVING count(d.DepartmentId) = 1
        );
```

**Result:**

```
+-----------+-------------+
| studentid | studentname |
+-----------+-------------+
|         3 | Andy        |
|         4 | Joe         |
+-----------+-------------+
```

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/HDK20931)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
SELECT st.StudentId, St.StudentName
FROM student st
     JOIN Department dep ON dep.StudentId = st.StudentId
GROUP BY st.StudentId
HAVING COUNT(dep.DepartmentId) = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to eliminate the students having multiple departments at the beginning by using a `cte` table, then use the table with `IN` keyword like:

```
with cte as (
   select StudentId
   from Department
   group by StudentId
   having count(StudentId)=1  
)
select *
from Students
where StudentId in (select StudentId from cte)
```